# Automysqlbackup how long does it keep the backups

Tags: mysql, backup

I wonder that if you setup automysqlbackup with default config, how long does it keep the old backups?

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2010-01-27 17:20 daily
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2010-01-27 17:20 monthly
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2010-01-27 17:20 weekly
root@server1:~#
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this question is off-topic. It should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

You should never use AutoMySQLBackup script without configuring it.

Settings for rotation are clearly described in the [configuration file](https://github.com/jadb/mysql-autobackup/blob/master/automysqlbackup.conf).

```
# Set rotation of daily backups. VALUE*24hours
# If you want to keep only today's backups, you could choose 1, 
# i.e. everything older than 24hours will be removed.
#CONFIG_rotation_daily=6

# Set rotation for weekly backups. VALUE*24hours
#CONFIG_rotation_weekly=35

# Set rotation for monthly backups. VALUE*24hours
#CONFIG_rotation_monthly=150
```

Comment: As the readme says (there are no config directives like those commented out): automysqlbackup creates backup every day, week and month for all of your MySQL
 database, to a configured folder. There's nothing to do but to install this
 package, and you'll rest assured that you have a way to go back in the
 history of your database.

 The package include the adequate cron entries so that it automatically
 performs the backup as configured.

 All parameters can be setup by editing the /etc/default/automysqlbackup file

Comment: Have you red the configuration file mentioned? It shoud have these lines.

Comment: This is 2.6+debian.3-1  it doesn't have any additional config file.

Comment: If you say so, but how came the readme mention a nonexistent configuration file, namely `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`?

Comment: @EsaJokinen you are referring to a *fork* of `automysqlbackup` at it is clearly mentioned on the [project page](https://github.com/jadb/mysql-autobackup). This is not the version that gets installed with `apt` on debian like systems.